# Razor - Passing Selected value as a parameter to call Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor Syntax. In my issue scenarion, I have a `select` dropdown, And when the user selects `empName`, a Pop Up opens. In this `Popup` I call a method with Razor which takes 2 parameters. the `2nd parameter` is the `empName`(`value selected in select dropdown`).

How to pass this selected value as a 2nd parameter?

```
<select id="empName">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
</select
```

HTML of Pop Up Dialog, Which opens when User selects & clicks Open PopUp Btn.

```
<div>
    @foreach (var item in new obj.getMasterFields('Category', par2))
    {
         <label for="@item.Key">@item.Value</label> <br />
         ....
    }
</div>
```

Note : The Popup is Twitter Bootstrap Modal opened with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap modal pop up, you can do the following:

> 1. Render the content of your pop up in the server.  By using this method, you might want to expose one AJAX function in your controller
>      that serve this request. Pass the selected dropdown list to the server
>      and expect HTML content returned. By doing this way, you can expect
>      the selected dropdownlist value is recognized in the Razor as the
>      process is done in server side.
> 2. Render the content of your pop up in the client side.    In using this way, you can't achieve the question you asked as Razor is not
>      involved because it's not involving request to the web server.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: The popup is in the same page...It's opened with Bootstrap Modal PopUp..!

Comment: Noted. The posted is updated. Please also help to update your question about bootstrap modal pop up. Thanks